# Cant save timestamp values in hibernate oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.13 and Spring 4

If I try to store timestamp values on Oracle, it fails. But surprisingly, it works on OracleXE. Only difference in schema is, On Oracle I have partition on that table. On OracleXE, I dont.

On Oracle, 
While printing entity it shows value correctly.

> 2018-03-19 11:25:59.456 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : qtp771935287-17] -
>   net.jigarshah.domain.MyEntity{myId=123123,
>   myUuid=ef5c5159-1e91-4a8e-a3bb-8f583fb3cce2,
>   **receivedOn=2018-03-19T11:25:59.277+01:00[Arctic/Longyearbyen]**, errorCode=null,
>   **lastUpdatedOn=2018-03-19T11:25:59.274+01:00[Arctic/Longyearbyen]**, id=42001, status=RECEIVED}

In Insert it just removed those values

> 2018-03-19 11:25:59.470 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] -
>   **binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]**
>
> 2018-03-19 11:25:59.470 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] -
>   **binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]**

Complete logs

```
2018-03-19 11:25:59.278 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager : qtp771935287-17] - Initiating transaction commit
2018-03-19 11:25:59.278 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager : qtp771935287-17] - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[net.jigarshah.domain.MyEntity#42001]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@425f14f6 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@390223c9 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@611117d9 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1bb9208a collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@21fb6faf collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@94f1c32 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@60897d1d collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3266acf6 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.278 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl : qtp771935287-17] - committing
2018-03-19 11:25:59.278 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener : qtp771935287-17] - Processing flush-time cascades
2018-03-19 11:25:59.278 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener : qtp771935287-17] - Dirty checking collections
2018-03-19 11:25:59.455 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener : qtp771935287-17] - Flushed: 1 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2018-03-19 11:25:59.455 DEBUG [org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener : qtp771935287-17] - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2018-03-19 11:25:59.455 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : qtp771935287-17] - Listing entities:
2018-03-19 11:25:59.456 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter : qtp771935287-17] - net.jigarshah.domain.MyEntity{myId=123123, myUuid=ef5c5159-1e91-4a8e-a3bb-8f583fb3cce2, receivedOn=2018-03-19T11:25:59.277+01:00[Arctic/Longyearbyen], errorCode=null, lastUpdatedOn=2018-03-19T11:25:59.274+01:00[Arctic/Longyearbyen], id=42001, status=RECEIVED}
2018-03-19 11:25:59.468 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger : qtp771935287-17] -
    insert
    into
        my_entity
        (my_id, error_code, last_updated_on, received_on, my_uuid, status, id)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-03-19 11:25:59.469 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [123123]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.469 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.470 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] - binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.470 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.470 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] - binding parameter [5] as [BINARY] - [ef5c5159-1e91-4a8e-a3bb-8f583fb3cce2]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.471 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.EnumType$EnumValueMapperSupport : qtp771935287-17] - Binding [RECEIVED] to parameter: [6]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.472 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : qtp771935287-17] - binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [42001]
2018-03-19 11:25:59.472 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch : qtp771935287-17] - Executing batch size: 1
```

Type conversion

```
LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
builder.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);
builder.scanPackages(packages);
builder.addProperties(createHibernateProperties());
new **StandardTypeOverrideApplier**(builder).apply();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = builder.buildSessionFactory();
return sessionFactory;
```

Type converter

```
private Configuration configuration;

public StandardTypeOverrideApplier(Configuration configuration) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
public void apply() {
        configuration.registerTypeOverride(jvm(new org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime()), new String[]{"jodaDateTime", DateTime.class.getName()});
        configuration.registerTypeOverride(new org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate(), new String[]{"jodaLocalDate", org.joda.time.LocalDate.class.getName()});
        **configuration.registerTypeOverride(new PersistentZonedDateTime(), new String[]{"zonedDateTime", ZonedDateTime.class.getName()});**
        configuration.registerTypeOverride(new PersistentLocalDate(), new String[]{"localDate", LocalDate.class.getName()});
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit...I am using Spring LocalSessionFactoryBuilder to initialise sessionFactory with type converter. Added the same in Original text

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do with Type conversion. Issue was with SavOrUpdateEvent Listner.

I was updating receivedOn value in saveOrUpdate event Listner. Unfortunately, hibernate first creates insert query which does not have timestamp. and Then update query to update receivedOn. And since I had index on receivedOn, if never created update query. It was always failing on insert itself. I would really appriciate if anyone knows alter native to @PreCreate and @PreUpdate in case of hibernate saveOrUpdate. (unfortunately we cant get rid of saveOrUpdate due to some historical reasons in code base)